# Dynamically bound DataGridView shows -1 value on auto-increment column?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've dynamically bind datagridview with my database table and ContactId column is autoincrement in my database table when i click on last row in gridview to insert data it shows me -1 then on next -2 when i save the contents and then again open it shows properly why such a behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative values are temporary keys. Needed to make proper foreign key relations etc. And indeed replaced when the Db generates the real keys.